# Only user and group IDs may be used in inline mentions

Tags: apex, chatter, connect-api

I'm creating Chatter feed items using connect API apex. I want a simple message that contains a link to the user and a related object, e.g. opportunity. I'm getting this message when running the code below - Only user and group IDs may be used in inline mentions

How do I have a link to an object? Do I just create a hyperlink?

This would be perfect if I could override the displayed text LinkSegmentInput.

```
public static void postNewFeedItem(Id groupId, User user, Id objectId, String message) {

 ConnectApi.FeedType feedType = ConnectApi.FeedType.Record;
 String userToMention = user.Id;

 ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
 messageInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

 ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
 textSegment.text = 'User '+user.Name;
 messageInput.messageSegments.add(textSegment);

 ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegment = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
 mentionSegment.id = userToMention;
 messageInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegment);

 textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
 textSegment.text = message ;
 messageInput.messageSegments.add(textSegment);

 ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegment = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
 mentionSegment.id = objectId;
 messageInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegment);

 ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
 input.body = messageInput;

 ConnectApi.FeedItem feedItemRep = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(null, feedType, groupId, input, null);

}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. go ahead